# parse numbers from string

Tags: python, regex

i have a string as follows

```
text1: 123 wwer 123 text2: 456 oirn 456
```

i am trying to parse out numbers after text1. I am making some mistake i am not able to trace out.

```
import re
if re.search("text1",string):
    re.findall("\d+",st)
>>> if re.search("text1",st):
re.findall("\d+",st)
['1', '123', '123', '2', '456', '456']
```

But my intention is to parse out 123 alone. what mistake i am doing

output should be [123,123] for text1 and [456,456] for text2

Comment: i need both 1233 from the text. Sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: See http://ideone.com/XDv9I9 for a dynamic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will split it into two parts.

1) split the whole string into parts wherever `text\d` appears.
2) iterate through the list, and find all the numbers.

```
>>> import re
>>> st = 'text1: 123 wwer 123 text2: 456 oirn 456'
>>> lst = re.split(r'(text\d)',st)[1:]
>>> {i:re.findall(r'\d+',j) for i,j in zip(lst, lst[1:])[::2]}
{'text2': ['456', '456'], 'text1': ['123', '123']}
```

Comment: i need both the numbers from it

Comment: What numbers? the first numbers after both `test1` and `test2`? Or, both numbers of `test1` itself?

Comment: the output should be like [123,123] for text1, and for text2 [456,456]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex: `(text\d+):[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/En7vCp/2)

Comment: This solution assumes there will be *two and only two* numbers .

Comment: That's right, but that match the OP needs. I'll change it if assumption changes. We don't know this right now ;)

Comment: still it returns all possible matches including 456

Answer (score 0):

Short solution:

```
text = 'text1: 123 wwer 123 text2: 456 oirn 456'
result = [list(i) for i in re.findall(r'text\d+: (\d+) \w+ (\d+)', text)]
print(result)
```

The output(consequtive pairs):

```
[['123', '123'], ['456', '456']]
```